# progress bar only works on page load/reload only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Disclaimer:** Tis code is taken from this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6m9gf2a2/34/)

I want to have youtube.com like progressbar, I have tried in this way

```js
$('#search').click(function(){ 
  $({property: 0}).animate({property: 105}, {
    duration: 4000,
    step: function() {
      var _percent = Math.round(this.property);

      $('#progress').css('width',  _percent+"%");
      if(_percent == 105) {
        $("#progress").addClass("done");
      }
    },
    complete: function() {

    }
  });

});
```

```css
  #progress {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 2147483647;
        top: 0;
        left: -6px;
        width: 0%;
        height: 2px;
        background: #b91f1f;
        -moz-border-radius: 1px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
        border-radius: 1px;
        -moz-transition: width 500ms ease-out,opacity 400ms linear;
        -ms-transition: width 500ms ease-out,opacity 400ms linear;
        -o-transition: width 500ms ease-out,opacity 400ms linear;
        -webkit-transition: width 500ms ease-out,opacity 400ms linear;
        transition: width 500ms ease-out,opacity 400ms linear
    }
    #progress.done {
        opacity: 0
    }
    #progress dd,#progress dt {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        height: 2px;
        -moz-box-shadow: #b91f1f 1px 0 6px 1px;
        -ms-box-shadow: #b91f1f 1px 0 6px 1px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: #b91f1f 1px 0 6px 1px;
        box-shadow: #b91f1f 1px 0 6px 1px;
        -moz-border-radius: 100%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
        border-radius: 100%
    }
    #progress dd {
        opacity: 1;
        width: 20px;
        right: 0;
        clip: rect(-6px,22px,14px,10px)
    }
    #progress dt {
        opacity: 1;
        width: 180px;
        right: -80px;
        clip: rect(-6px,90px,14px,-6px)
    }
    @-moz-keyframes pulse {
        30% {
            opacity: 1
        }
        60% {
            opacity: 0
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1
        }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes pulse {
        30% {
            opacity: .6
        }
        60% {
            opacity: 0
        }
        100% {
            opacity: .6
        }
    }
    @-o-keyframes pulse {
        30% {
            opacity: 1
        }
        60% {
            opacity: 0
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes pulse {
        30% {
            opacity: .6
        }
        60% {
            opacity: 0
        }
        100% {
            opacity: .6
        }
    }
    @keyframes pulse {
        30% {
            opacity: 1
        }
        60% {
            opacity: 0
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1
        }
    }
    #progress.waiting dd,#progress.waiting dt {
        -moz-animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
        -ms-animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
        -o-animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
        -webkit-animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
        animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progress" class="waiting">
    <dt></dt>
    <dd></dd>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="search" value="Search" />
```

but it only works one time after page is loaded, I want this must work when ever I click `Search` button.

Comment: Any news on your question? Did the answer help or is something still missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `done` class from your `progress` div before starting new.

```
$("#progress").removeClass("done");
```

Its a litte more difficult to avoid the progress bar to first move back after starting new. First reset the width of it to 0, directly after adding `done`:

```
$("#progress").addClass("done").css('width', 0);
```

Due to the `opacity` transition, there is still some milliseconds when the bar going back to zero width is visible. So I ended up with simply hiding it (which sets its `display` property).

Here's the complete code:

```
$('#search').click(function(){
  $("#progress").removeClass("done").show();
  $({property: 0}).animate({property: 105}, {
    duration: 4000,
    step: function() {
      var _percent = Math.round(this.property);

      $('#progress').css('width',  _percent+"%");
      if(_percent == 105) {
        $("#progress").addClass("done").hide();
      }
    },
    complete: function() {

    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (I added comments on what I changed)

```js
$('#search').click(function(){ 
  $("#progress").removeClass("done");
  $({property: 0}).animate({property: 105}, {
    duration: 4000,
    step: function() {
      var _percent = Math.round(this.property);

     
      if(_percent == 105) {
         $('#progress').hide(); //make it invisible
         $('#progress').css('width', "0%"); //Reset to 0
      }else{
         $('#progress').show(); //show it.
         $('#progress').css('width',  _percent+"%"); //progress
      }
    },
    complete: function() {

    }
  });

});
```

```css
  #progress {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 2147483647;
        top: 0;
        left: -6px;
        width: 0%;
        height: 2px;
        background: #b91f1f;
        -moz-border-radius: 1px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
        border-radius: 1px;
        -moz-transition: width 500ms ease-out,opacity 400ms linear;
        -ms-transition: width 500ms ease-out,opacity 400ms linear;
        -o-transition: width 500ms ease-out,opacity 400ms linear;
        -webkit-transition: width 500ms ease-out,opacity 400ms linear;
        transition: width 500ms ease-out,opacity 400ms linear
    }
    #progress.done {
        opacity: 0
    }
    #progress dd,#progress dt {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        height: 2px;
        -moz-box-shadow: #b91f1f 1px 0 6px 1px;
        -ms-box-shadow: #b91f1f 1px 0 6px 1px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: #b91f1f 1px 0 6px 1px;
        box-shadow: #b91f1f 1px 0 6px 1px;
        -moz-border-radius: 100%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
        border-radius: 100%
    }
    #progress dd {
        opacity: 1;
        width: 20px;
        right: 0;
        clip: rect(-6px,22px,14px,10px)
    }
    #progress dt {
        opacity: 1;
        width: 180px;
        right: -80px;
        clip: rect(-6px,90px,14px,-6px)
    }
    @-moz-keyframes pulse {
        30% {
            opacity: 1
        }
        60% {
            opacity: 0
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1
        }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes pulse {
        30% {
            opacity: .6
        }
        60% {
            opacity: 0
        }
        100% {
            opacity: .6
        }
    }
    @-o-keyframes pulse {
        30% {
            opacity: 1
        }
        60% {
            opacity: 0
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes pulse {
        30% {
            opacity: .6
        }
        60% {
            opacity: 0
        }
        100% {
            opacity: .6
        }
    }
    @keyframes pulse {
        30% {
            opacity: 1
        }
        60% {
            opacity: 0
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1
        }
    }
    #progress.waiting dd,#progress.waiting dt {
        -moz-animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
        -ms-animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
        -o-animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
        -webkit-animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
        animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progress" class="waiting">
    <dt></dt>
    <dd></dd>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="search" value="Search" />
```

Comment: Is there any thing really different to my answer?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be, I had it on my screen and had to step away, came back and clicked post, didn't mean to post over you.